# Neat alignment of titlerule, text in tabular, and text in longtable

Tags: tables, spacing, lengths

I'm having some trouble getting things to line up neatly. To be clear, I don't want everything to be the 'same length,' rather, I want it to fit aesthetically so that with multiple sections and multiple fields, it all looks 'neat' together.

A MWE

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    inner=20mm,
    outer=30mm,
    top=20mm,
    bottom=20mm,
    heightrounded,
}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\sloppy

\titleformat{\section}{\Large}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2pt}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\section{\enspace{Foobar}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{rL}
    foo & \blindtext\\
\end{tabulary}

\begin{longtable}{>{\hfill}m{2.57cm}|>{\arraybackslash}p{14.55cm}}
    foobar & \begin{minipage}[t]{14.8cm}
        \blindtext
    \end{minipage}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The intended form will have some dates and such on the left, and longer entries on the right. Thank you for any help and advice.

Edit: I should also clarify that the text on the left is not necessarily meant to align between the two. Ie., the text in the tabulary would ideally be pushed to the centre (somewhat) of the page - I am concerned here with the right margin alignment of text.

Comment: Could you please add a sketch of the desired output? Your current description "fit aesthetically"  and "all looks 'neat' together" is quite vague and might differ depending on personal taste.

Comment: Probably you are interested in something like `\noindent
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{l|X}
    foobar &  \blindtext\\
\end{xltabular}` for the second table? (Needs the `xltabular` package).

Comment: You can never have a neat output when you are using `\sloppy`.

Comment: I have looked at your MWE and your description. It is very unclear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code line up some of the text, but please describe what you actually are after:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    inner=20mm,
    outer=30mm,
    top=20mm,
    bottom=20mm,
    heightrounded,
}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2pt}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\section{\hspace{\tabcolsep}{Foobar}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{w{r}{0.5cm}X}
    foo & \blindtext\\
\end{tabularx}

\begin{xltabular}[r]{\dimexpr(\linewidth-0.5cm-2\tabcolsep)}{>{\raggedright}p{2.57cm}|>{\arraybackslash}X}
    foobar & \begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
        \blindtext
    \end{minipage}
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I apologise for the vagueness of the question, I couldn't think of how better to phrase it. Apologies as well for the lateness of the reply - I figured out a solution myself in the interim, and forgot to check back in the business of the interim. 
The text being lined up is almost exactly what I wanted. Thank you for the good will and help in the face of my lack of clarity.